# RGBa in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, css, rgba

I know that IE does not support RGBa. I also know that you can use the follow methods:

```
/* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
/* For IE 8*/
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
```

The first two Numbers in the "Colorstr" is the value for the opacity. with 99 being a .6 opacity.  For other levels of opacity what are the number values? I cannot find them. Is there a simple way to calculate the number for opacity? Or where can I find those values?

Thanks =>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it's straight 1-byte hexadecimal, so just do this

Say your opacity is 30%:

```
.30 * 255 = 76.5
76 -> hex = 4C
```

You can convert decimal to hex using a variety of desktop tools, online pages, or this JS function:

```
new Number(76).toString(16);
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is the most straight forward => I found this site: http://www.statman.info/conversions/hexadecimal.html that offers a very easy to use tool to convert to hex like you have done.

Comment: I think you must multiple 256 and take 1:
.30 * 256 - 1 = 75.8 (it's just the theory and I could be wrong).

Comment: What about hex to decimal? How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

It's a hexidecimal 99 which is 153 in decimal.  type 0x99 in a js console and it will spit out 153.  F is the highest digit in hex so typing in 0xff (the highest value for two hex digits) will give you 255.  if 255 is 100% and 153 is the value you want to know the percentage of you divide 153 by 255 which results in 0.6.

Answer (score 0):

sure, use a hex to percentage converter like [this](http://www.december.com/html/spec/colorcodes.html):

`#999999` converts to **rgb(60%, 60%, 60%)** so 99 = 60%

`#BABABA` converts to **rgb(73%, 73%, 73%)** so BA = 73%

you can probably find a better hex converter than the one I've suggested. Remember that hex is base 16, not 10...

Comment: see the other answers provided by Joseph and OverZealous for the mathematics behind this

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2011, Internet Explorer 9+ DOES process rgba correctly, and, in fact, does so more accurately/thoroughly than [Chrome|Mozilla|Safari]...