# Transparent background rendering White in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, jquery-cycle

In my page layout I have two `<div>` tags. One, with id `#image-panel` and the other with `#image-content-panel`.
The two `<div>`s are stacked on top of each other using `position: absolute`. `#image-content-panel` (has higher `z-index`) is on top of `#image-panel`.
Both `<div>`s have `background: transparent`.

The page renders fine in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox i.e. I can see the image through the text (heading and paragraph etc.). But in IE (version 8) `#image-content-panel` is being redered with a white background.

You can see screenshots below:

[Rendering in Crome, Safari, Mozilla](http://tinypic.com/r/3465ief/6)

[Rendering in IE 8](http://tinypic.com/r/333buy8/6)

Relevant CSS and HTML code :

[HTML Code](http://pastebin.ca/2201291)

[CSS Code](http://pastebin.ca/2201294)

I'd like the page to render same in IE too.
Any help is appreciated.
Please propose an Alternative solution too if this can't be fixed.

Comment: See this about [RGBa support in Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935772/rgba-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: Can you please put the code in jsfiddle.net. That way, it would be easier for some of us to figure out the problem. Also, one alternative solution i would like to suggest is to use a separate stylesheet for IE8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** 
The [Jquery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) will add a background colour to elements in older versions of IE.

You need to set the `cleartypeNoBg` option to `true` in your Cycle initialisation.

```
$("#image-content-panel").cycle({
    fx : 'scrollRight',
    speed : 2700,
    cleartypeNoBg: true 
});
```

**EDIT** The below is not relevent

IE8 doesn't support rgba values and will fallback to a solid colour. If you don't define a fallback it will default to white which is what you are seeing.

There's a couple of ways to handle this.

**1. Accept IE8's limitations.**

```
    #header {
        z-index: 100 !important;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background: rgb(0,0,0);
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    }
```

`#header` will have a solid black background in browsers that don;t support rgba. Semi opaque in browsers that do.

**2.Use a filter**

```
    #header {
        z-index: 100 !important;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)"
        margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    }
```

`#header` will have 60% transparent black background in IE8 and proper browsers. Personally, I hate using filters. They make your markup hideous and are difficult to maintain unless you are excellent at converting rgb to hex codes in your head (which I'm not). Also, this particular filter is IE8+. It will not work in IE7, though there are other filters that will work in IE6-7. You should also probably separate this out in to an IE8 specific stylesheet or use some other method to prevent IE9 from using the filter as IE9 supports rgba.

**3.Use a 1px x 1px black, semi-transparent .png**

```
    #header {
        z-index: 100 !important;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background: url(background.png) repeat;
        margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    }
```

This is the route I usually go down simply because it's simple. It takes seconds to create a .png if you need to change the alpha and you don't need to worry about browser inconsistencies.

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself well enough. My Problem has nothing to to with `#header` or its background. it is about `#image-content-panel` which has `background:transparent` but rendering with white bg in IE, so I can't see the Image behind it. the image is being hidden partly by `#image-content-panel` . Please compare two screenshots

Comment: Bravo! from where you got that `cleartypeNoBg:true` thing ?. I wish I could up-vote twice. Thanks !

Comment: I've used it in the past. It will be mentioned somewhere in the  Cycle options reference. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, IE8 doesn't support RGBA colour values.

There is a hack you can use to work around this though: I recommend trying out [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) on your site; it implements a number of modern CSS features into old versions of IE, including RGBA colours in backgrounds.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself well enough. My Problem has nothing to to with `#header` or its background. it is about `#image-content-panel` which has `background:transparent` but rendering with white bg in IE, so I can't see the Image behind it. the image is being hidden partly by `#image-content-panel` . Please compare two screenshots